# Morley’s Categoricity Theorem for uncountable languages.

Tags: reference-request, model-theory

Where can I find an accessible exposition of Shelah’s generalization of Morley’s theorem to uncountable languages? (Please, do not answer “Shelah’s *Classification Theory*”.)

Comment: Have you looked at Shelah’s original paper (which I don’t think is discussed in his book)? As far as I know, everybody seems to only want to discuss categoricity in the context of countable languages.

Comment: The best that I can find is [this article](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~jbaldwin/pub/zilrev1.pdf) by Zilber, which discusses the $ \mathcal{L}_{\omega_{1},\omega} $-version of Morley’s Categoricity Theorem. It also talks about some of Shelah’s work.

Comment: Accessible expositions of Shelah's work are hard to find. I personally haven't seen any exposition of Morley's theorem for uncountable languages not by Shelah.